# Enable clean urls through htaccess - modrewrite in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I'm trying to set up a Drupal installation to be able to have clean urls. I have searched for the .htaccess-file in the root-folder, but haven't found it. In the phpinfo-file I created, I see under Loaded Modules mod_rewrite, so it is enabled on the server.
I created a .htaccess-file which contained a simple

```
RewriteEngine On
```

But when I ran the test under Configuration -> Search and metadata -> Clean URLs, it still failed. I then uploaded a .htaccess-file a friend sent me from a Drupal installation, but the test still failed.

What now?

Answer (score 2):

The `.htaccess` for Drupal is *a lot* more complicated than a single line, I suggest you download a fresh copy of Drupal and take the `.htaccess` file out of the root folder and use that. If you can't find it I suggest turning on hidden files, there are different ways of doing this depending on your OS.

For a quick fix sake, adding these lines should sort your issue:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Alas it didn't, the test still fails.

Comment: Here is the full .htaccess: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/96f9b739c84bd2527707